# Insert new rows in table using QGIS and PostGIS view and do instead trigger

Tags: qgis, postgis, trigger

I have a table with roads and use a view to populate descriptive fields from look-up tables.
I can see the view in QGIS and would like to use it to add new roads using a DO INSTEAD trigger.
Currently the trigger adds one row with the new data for every row in the view and not just for the one or two new rows ( ie if the view has 2000 rows I get 2000 new rows in the table that all look like the new row)
How do I get the trigger to do the same as the insert on the table which correctly adds a new id (serial) for each new row without manually adding the id?

Comment: I created a simple view (select * from table) and it was working immediately. I guess you need to give more information: Table definition, Trigger, Rules

Comment: Can we see your code?